# Resizing the height of the selection indicator in a UIPickerView

Tags: objective-c, selection, uipickerview, row-height

in an App I have to maintain I had to set the rowHeight of a UIPickerView row to the value of 66. Now it can properly display three lines of text.

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
 return 66;
}
```

Now the selection indicator height is too small for a row.
Can anybody help me finding out how I can increase the height of that selection indicator?

Many thanks in advance.
Uwe

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it's impossible.

But if you want a useful selection indicator, the solution is to draw a custom selection indicator with proper dimensions (The background must be transparent) and then adds to the UIPickerView as a subview (Don't forget to set the frame correctly).
So the result will be a UIPickerView with an UIImageView in the middle that represents the selection indicator.

I hope it helps,

Arildo